# Using Paramiko for server

Tags: python, ssh, client, paramiko

I was wondering, I want to create a SSH server and a client with custom commands. 
I thought of using Twisted for it, but I did not go well with the docs. 
I decided to use Paramiko, but I wonder, is there any way to create a Paramiko server? Or only client?
Another question, let's say you can only create a client, can I create the client in Paramiko and the server using the socket module and connect to it? Is this possible?
If so, any advice? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Paramiko can be used both as an SSH client and server; see [paramiko.Transport.start_server](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Transport-class.html#start_server) to get started.

If you go back and revisit Twisted, [twisted.conch](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedConch) also implements SSH.